# Project image onto a sphere

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, asymptote

Is there an easy way to project an equirectangular image onto a sphere in LaTeX, kinda like shown here:

[image: Projection]

I'm sorry this question is rather short, but I can't find anything on the matter on google.

Comment: I have not yet know how to do that, just suggest adding tag `asymptote` to get more attention to your question.

Comment: This sort of pixel-by-pixel transform would be too slow for LaTeX, and too complicated for most graphics editors.

Comment: To my knowledge, `asymptote` does not manage texture (even if with OpenGL it is possible to implement this feature)